# How can i reduce the size of an image and then upload it to google drive?

Tags: image, upload, base64, reduce, image-size

I have an image that comes from an html `input type= "File"`

The file is being  base64 converted using the `javascript` function
`btoa(file)` and then with a request is sent to google drive.

Thanks in Advance